# Python Dictionary: Serialized Strings

Tags: python-2.7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDWjp.png)

I have defined a python dictionary named "values" as shown above and it has several rows. I am trying to access the key:value pair for each row one by one if the key named "Risk: is high. I tried something like :

```
for i in range(len(rows)-1):
   a = []
   if values["Risk"][i]=='high':
     a.append(values[key][i])
```

But the problem is it just appends the first character of each value. So instead of getting the vale 'Male' against the key 'Gender', I got 'M'. I am new to python and don't really understand the issue here.
Any suggestions?
Thanks!!

Comment: can you please paste an example of your `values` dictionary as text in your question as well as `rows`? The image is cropped for me and generally less helpful than text

Comment: @rbierman I agree, +1 for you.

Comment: dict_items([('HairLength', 'Short'), ('Employed?', 'Yes'), ('Age', 'Young'), ('Student?', 'No'), ('PreviouslyDeclined?', 'No'), ('Risk', 'high'), ('FirstLoan', 'No'), ('Gender', 'Male'), ('TypeOfColateral', 'Car'), ('LifeInsurance', 'Yes')])
dict_items([('HairLength', 'Short'), ('Employed?', 'Yes'), ('Age', 'Young'), ('Student?', 'No'), ('PreviouslyDeclined?', 'No'), ('Risk', 'high'), ('FirstLoan', 'Yes'), ('Gender', 'Male'), ('TypeOfColateral', 'Car'), ('LifeInsurance', 'No')])

Comment: rows is my file:                                                                              ['Gender', 'Male', 'Age', 'Young', 'Student?', 'No', 'PreviouslyDeclined?', 'No', 'HairLength', 'Short', 'Employed?', 'Yes', 'TypeOfColateral', 'Car', 'FirstLoan', 'No', 'LifeInsurance', 'Yes', 'Risk', 'high']
['Gender', 'Male', 'Age', 'Young', 'Student?', 'No', 'PreviouslyDeclined?', 'No', 'HairLength', 'Short', 'Employed?', 'Yes', 'TypeOfColateral', 'Car', 'FirstLoan', 'Yes', 'LifeInsurance', 'No', 'Risk', 'high']

Comment: Please edit those into your question.

Answer (score 0):

After spending a while, you should think how to get data from a source you're using, because they're inadequate to calculate on them. I wish to help you, but I think that if I'll know the source from you get items from both `dict` and `rows` I will solve this issue totally different. If you want to solve this issue and it's really valuable for you, then just add more data to your question. That's all I can write.

Comment: Yes but if does not give me the entire value.Instead it serializes and just appends the first character

Comment: @Peppy Just tell me what you want to achieve with these two lists and I will help you.

Comment: My Dictionary has 398 rows in total. Each row has 10 key:value pairs.For every row first I want to check the value of the key "Risk".If it is high then I want to append all the values in that row into a new list.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this isn't a direct answer to your question, but I think you are having difficulties because of the way you are storing the "loaner" information. If you switched to a class-based model everything would get easier, more intuitive, and less hard-coded:

```
class LoanInfo(object):
    __slots__ = ["HairLength","Employed","Age","Student",
                 "PreviouslyDeclined","Risk","FirstLoan","Gender",
                 "TypeOfColateral","LifeInsurance"]
    def __init__(self,HairLength,Employed,Age,Student,PreviouslyDeclined,Risk,FirstLoan,Gender,TypeOfColateral,LifeInsurance):
        self.HairLength = HairLength
        self.Employed = Employed
        self.Age = Age
        self.Student = Student
        self.PreviouslyDeclined = PreviouslyDeclined
        self.Risk = Risk
        self.FirstLoan = FirstLoan
        self.Gender = Gender
        self.TypeOfColateral = TypeOfColateral
        self.LifeInsurance = LifeInsurance


loan_info_1 = LoanInfo('Short', 'Yes', 'Young', 'No', 'No', 'high', 'No', 'Male', 'Car', 'Yes')
loan_info_2 = LoanInfo('Short', 'Yes', 'Young', 'No', 'No', 'high', 'Yes', 'Male', 'Car', 'No')

loaners = [loan_info_1, loan_info_2]
rows = loan_info_1.__slots__ #<-- the slots of the object are the rows you want

high_risk_genders = []
for loaner in loaners:
   if loaner.Risk == 'high':
     high_risk_genders.append(loaner.Gender)

print high_risk_genders
```

output:

```
['Male', 'Male']
```

This is a more pythonic way of handling your problem. There is a lot of help online for python classes such as http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm

Comment: It's an insane answer. He has only about 300 of rows, there is no special need to define a class with __slots__ attribute. As I read Peppy, I see that he even wouldn't understand you write. Anyway thanks for your input, because I'm still trying understand what I should get as a result having these kind of data.